# XCode debugging preventing UIViewController from loading xib _every_other_time_

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, lldb

I have an application that runs perfectly when executed without XCode (not running it via the "Run" button) both on the simulator and on the actual device.

When the application is executed in Xcode however (no matter the kind of device: word size, real/simulator, format doesn't count), one of my controllers fail to load the xib exactly **every other time**.

```
run app -> Interface ok
run app -> White space
run app -> Interface ok
run app -> White space...
```

And so on, and on...

I have traced all calls, and the application behaves the same way from my code perspective every time, the only difference is that after the view of the controller loads, half the time I get the subviews while the other half I get self.view.subviews == @[]. Also same logs from my application in the ok/non ok executions.

I'm using

```
[[Controller alloc] init];
```

to load the controller (though it shouldn't matter...)

But now for the funny part. I can delete the app, or even format the simulator, and the next run will remember how the last run went **xD**

```
format the device -> run app (Xcode) -> interface ok
format the device -> run app (Xcode) -> white space
format the device -> run app (Xcode) -> interface ok
format the device -> run app (Xcode) -> white space..
```

and so on... Which means that the problem is somewhat in the state of Xcode and it's debugger and not in my app.

Xcode is version 5.1.1, I'm running Maverick 10.9.4 and iOs is 7.1.2.

Any suggestion about how to prevent this (rather annoying...) problem?

**UPDATE:** 
checked the devices logs for the working/bugged run: no discernible pattern

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the problem is probably an Xcode bug.

The problem stem from the fact that the xib in question was not in the project directory, but in an external one (the reasons are of no consequence for the problem at hand, but had to do with easing the developing of a Cordova/Phonegap plugin).

In the project directory there was a blank xib file with the same name, and for some reason, Xcode was installing the correct xib and the blank one with the app, intermittently (which is what is screaming **xcode bug!!!** to me)...

The fact that the application *always* worked when run without xcode was luck (or misfortune, depending on the point of view...): it could have just not worked all the time, because the discriminant was whether Xcode had installed the correct xib or not, then the app continued to behave accordingly.

Hope it helps someone else (it was *sort of funny* anyway...)